# Crear matriz 10 x10 con numeros aleatorios en php

Tags: php

Hola estoy intentando hacer una matriz en php con numeros aleatorios, solo puedo hacer un array pero la matriz de 10x10 no puedo esto es lo que llevo de codigo espero y me puedan ayudar

```
<?php
    $numeros = array();
    for ($i=0; $i <10; $i++) { 
        $aleatorio = rand(1,100);
        array_push($numeros, $aleatorio);
    }
    for ($i=0; $i <count($numeros); $i++) { 
        echo $numeros[$i]," ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Se pueden repetir los números?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar [range()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.range.php) y solucionarlo de esta manera:

```
foreach ( range( 1, 10 ) as $ejeY) {

  foreach ( range( 1, 10 ) as $ejeX ) {

    // Aquí creamos los ejes con un valor aleatorio 
    $ejesYX[ $ejeY ][ $ejeX ] = rand( 1, 100 );
  }
}

print_r( $ejesYX );
```

<kbd>[**Ver demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cde4745a367a0595ac5fe16c89fea28b7f5bea99)</kbd>

---

**Edit:**

Para mostrar el resultado de `$ejesYX` en una tabla (html):

```
<?php

$ejeX = range( 1, 10 );
$ejeY = range( 1, 10 );

foreach ( $ejeY as $y ) {

  foreach ( $ejeX as $x ) {
    // Aquí creamos los ejes con un valor aleatorio
    $ejesYX[ $y ][ $x ] = rand( 1, 100 );
  }
}

// Creamos la tabla
$html = '<table border>';
$html .= '<th></th>';

// Para crear las columnas X ( $ejeX = 1 a 10 )
foreach ( $ejeX as $col_X ) {

  $html .= '<th>'.$col_X.'</th>';
}

foreach ( $ejesYX as $col_Y => $valores ) {

  $html .= '<tr>';
  // Para crear las columnas Y ( $ejeY = 1 a 10 )
  $html .= '<td><b>'.$col_Y.'</b></td>';

  foreach ( $valores as $val ) {
    // Creamos los campos de los valores
    $html .= '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
  }

  $html .= '</tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;
```

Salida:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

1   37  25  100 55  36  42  46  48  7   34
2   45  43  40  51  50  88  94  28  34  100
3   53  72  78  19  88  94  75  66  78  88
4   69  37  94  90  85  99  38  88  59  61
5   15  82  43  16  22  1   28  18  36  83
6   92  48  11  26  28  82  74  70  64  62
7   29  69  14  54  70  63  57  37  51  66
8   25  21  98  1   69  75  91  60  86  12
9   67  36  72  26  54  83  64  11  53  12
10  80  40  94  33  98  82  7   25  66  72
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero para hacer que se vea como una tabla de 10 x10 solo los numeros?, perdon es que apenas estoy empezando y no entiendo mucho lo de las matrices

Comment: @Hector - Listo... he actualizado la respuesta.. saludos!

Answer (score 2):

En ese caso, lo único que te faltaría hacer sería mostrar en pantalla, por ejemplo en una tabla, lo que te ha calculado Black Sheep en su respuesta. Te lo encapsulo en una función y te lo hago con bucles for, únicamente por aportar más opciones.

```
<?php
    function matriz($a,$b,$min,$max){
        for($x=0;$x<$a;$x++)
            for($y=0;$y<$b;$y++)
                $r[$x][$y]=rand($min,$max);
        return $r;
    }

    $txt='<table border>';
    foreach(matriz(10,10,1,100) as $x){
        $txt.='<tr>';
        foreach($x as $xy) $txt.='<td>'.$xy.'</td>';
        $txt.='</tr>';
    }
    $txt.='</table>';
    echo $txt;
?>
```

El HTML resultante:

```html
<table border><tr><td>19</td><td>61</td><td>53</td><td>97</td><td>58</td><td>31</td><td>22</td><td>84</td><td>1</td><td>29</td></tr><tr><td>86</td><td>61</td><td>27</td><td>76</td><td>95</td><td>51</td><td>86</td><td>44</td><td>66</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>59</td><td>37</td><td>82</td><td>93</td><td>46</td><td>46</td><td>74</td><td>17</td><td>78</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>96</td><td>11</td><td>56</td><td>92</td><td>68</td><td>86</td><td>14</td><td>52</td><td>87</td></tr><tr><td>43</td><td>37</td><td>47</td><td>69</td><td>12</td><td>42</td><td>20</td><td>98</td><td>86</td><td>85</td></tr><tr><td>27</td><td>44</td><td>22</td><td>8</td><td>37</td><td>67</td><td>54</td><td>10</td><td>84</td><td>31</td></tr><tr><td>60</td><td>88</td><td>26</td><td>71</td><td>43</td><td>18</td><td>38</td><td>29</td><td>32</td><td>89</td></tr><tr><td>16</td><td>74</td><td>26</td><td>62</td><td>43</td><td>37</td><td>4</td><td>62</td><td>35</td><td>89</td></tr><tr><td>47</td><td>61</td><td>33</td><td>69</td><td>69</td><td>70</td><td>35</td><td>22</td><td>80</td><td>19</td></tr><tr><td>52</td><td>39</td><td>7</td><td>78</td><td>9</td><td>49</td><td>95</td><td>47</td><td>78</td><td>26</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te aporto una **solución para poder generar matrices CON o SIN elementos repetidos**.

La función `genMatriz()` genera un array multidimensional, por defecto de 10x10, con números del 1 al 100, sin repeticiones.

La función `printTable()` la añadí para presentar visualmente la matriz resultante. Acepta exactamente los mismos argumentos y la llama internamente.

```
<?php

function genMatriz(
    int $height=10,
    int $width=10,
    bool $repeat=false,
    array $elements=[]
): array
{
    if (! $elements) {
        $elements = range(1, ($height * $width));
    }

    for ($i=0; $i<$height; $i++) {
        $row = [];
        for ($j=0; $j<$width; $j++) {
            $num_elements_in_arr = count($elements);

            $position = rand(0, $num_elements_in_arr-1);
            $row[]    = $elements[$position];

            // to generate without repetitions -> clear the element in array
            if (! $repeat) {
                unset($elements[$position]);
                $elements = array_values($elements);
            }
        }
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    return $result;
}

function printTable(
    int $height=10,
    int $width=10,
    bool $repeat=false,
    array $elements=[])
{
    $arr = genMatriz($height, $width, $repeat, $elements);

    $html='';
    foreach ($arr as $row) {
        $html.='<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            $html .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $html.='</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '<table>' . PHP_EOL . $html . '</table>';
}

printTable();
```

La siguiente llamada:

```
printTable(4,4);
```

genera HTML para una tabla como la siguiente (añadí CSS para mejorar la visualización):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 1em auto; /* only for table */
    padding: 1em;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>13</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los 2 por sus respuestas, viendo sus codigos ya pude hacerlo "a mi manera" les dejo el codigo, nuevamente gracias

```
<?php
$numeros = array();

for ($i=0; $i <10; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j < 10; $j++) { 
        $numeros[$i][$j] = rand(1,100);
    }
    }
echo "<table border align = 'center'>";
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0; $j < 10; $j++) { 
        echo "<td>";  
        echo $numeros[$i][$j];
        echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```